# How do I reset Google Play Games leaderboards before publishing?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I've done some tests while integrating the new Google Play Games with fake scores, now I need to reset the leaderboards before publishing my game!

I found this REST API:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/management/api/?hl=en#Scores

But this seems to be related only to web games, not Android games:
"Use the Google Play game services REST API to set and retrieve game services data from your web game"

Thanks!

Comment: If you down vote a question, you should at least explain why...

Comment: I don't agree with this question being closed, this is a new service launched this week and I'm pretty sure there will be other people asking the same question, wondering how to reset unpublished leaderboard scores...

Comment: I dont agree too, this service is new and there no information in google api documentation.

Comment: Anyone interested on the answer, please vote to reopen this question! =)

Comment: Have you checked if you can reset them in the developer console?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Updating the answer as it is now possible to reset the leaderboard during development.

> You can only reset player progress data for your draft leaderboards.
>
> To reset leaderboards in the Google Play Developer Console, click the
>   button labeled Reset leaderboard progress at the bottom of the form
>   for that event. To reset leaderboard data programmatically, call the
>   Management API Scores methods.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards#resetting_a_leaderboard

Comment: This didn't work for me. My published leaderboard had the highscores from testing and was actually broken as a result. I had to delete it and replace it with another leaderboard.

Comment: Yes, anyone please don't believe this. I believed it and now all my scores are their in released version. Also, leaderboards cannot be reset after publishing the game and google game center.

Comment: This is working perfectly as described. Remember that this can be done only in draft leaderboards and **not** in published leaderboards.

Answer (score 18):

I ended up switching all my leaderboards in the Developer Console to use "lowest scores are best" instead of the previous "highest scores are best" and this seems to have reset the old scores that were saved. It's a bit of a hack but very useful. You could probably switch back again and everything would still be cleared.

Comment: This worked! I was able to switch it to Smaller is better, then immediately back to Larger is better. It immediately cleared the scores without having to rebuild anything.

Comment: Does it work on published leaderboard? I'd like to reset the leaderboard regularly once it is live, but didn't find a way to do so...

Comment: @Zennichimaro You cannot do that on a published leaderboard. Anyway, I want to confirm that this 'hack' still works - just did it now. I still don't know of any better way.

Comment: Working in an unpublished leaderboard

Answer (score 1):

#### Reset Test Achievements and Leaderboard Scores

As of Sep 9 2013 (From the Public issue tracker for the Play Games platform):

[Issue 9: reset leader board / achievement data.](https://code.google.com/p/play-games-platform/issues/detail?id=9&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Platform%20Summary%20Stars)

> If you are still in test phase, you can reset your Achievements by deleting your account from the Test list in your developer console and adding it again.