# How to remove a Google Play Leaderboard highscore

Tags: google-play-services, leaderboard

I've just published my game and I see that the high score from testing is still present as the high-score. How do I remove it/reset the leaderboard?

Comment: [Google Play Game Services Leaderboards](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards#editing_a_leaderboard)

Comment: Not sure why it was -1, it's a very valid question. What brought me here is not testing, but filtering out possible cheaters.

Comment: I predict this question will get visited a lot and hopefully answered soon. GDPR demands that data can be removed and the user forgotten.

Answer (score 4):

In game load leaderboard or achievements -- in right top corner click settings -- sharing -- Disconnect (with check box "also delete all activities in google"). It will remove all your scores

Answer (score 2):

Answer - you can't. Leaderboards are fixed after publishing and you can't remove entries. I could either hide the dubious score, or, as I did, create a new leaderboard and delete the old.

Importantly, this Stackoverflow question - [How do I reset Google Play Games leaderboards before publishing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607032/how-do-i-reset-google-play-games-leaderboards-before-publishing) - that I referred to before publishing was invalid. My test leaderboard was *not* reset upon publishing. In future I'll be sure that test scores are suitably low and irrelevant.

Comment: I didn't. I removed the old leaderboard and replaced it. The Google docs went into how you can hide specific scores IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

I'm approaching this question to remove any entries of possible cheaters.
I see an API method to hide a certain player:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/management/api/players

Same in REST API:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/management/api/?hl=en#Players

Someone can also enable Anti-Piracy (https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/antipiracy) for the app, Tamper protection for the leader board (http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/12/21/google-play-games-introduces-new-publishing-api-and-leaderboard-tamper-protection-improves-unity-plugin-and-c-sdk/), but that only seems to be advisable if you are Android only and you don't have iOS and HTML release.

Answer (score 0):

*NOTE:* Only draft leaderboards can be deleted. Only highscores on draft leaderboards earned by testers can be reset.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your score on the older leaderboard remains as client (device) side data after it was removed from server (Google Cloud platform) side.

You can delete such client side data with **Play Game app** as @АртемЯковенко answered.

1. Go **Settings** in Play Game app

[image: Go Settings in Play Game app]

2. Delete Play Games account & data

[image: Delete Play Games account & data]

3. Select the testing game from the **Delete individual game data** section

[image: Select the testing game from the Delete individual game data section]

4. Confirm to delete

[image: Confirm to delete]

Thus I could delete the older leaderboard data completely from client side.