# Monthly leaderboard for android game

Tags: android, leaderboard

I am building a simple single player game and need an incremental leaderboard and want to give some prize to the top 3 player each month. Initially I thought of using google service leaderboard.

My intial plan was to create separate leaderboard for each month.
However the problem we cannot delete/clear all data  a leaderboard once game is published. So we cannot clear all data from January and use them in next year January. Also we can have maximum of 70 leaderboard. So i cannot have separate leaderboard for each year and each month. (I can continue for 5 year 8 months thought :))

1. Is their any other solution for monthly leaderboard already
   available?
2. Can we somehow tweak the existing google play
   leaderboard to make it monthly ?

Comment: You can clear a leaderboard by setting it "lowest scores are best" instead of the previous "highest scores are best" or vice versa. At least that used to work according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607032/how-do-i-reset-google-play-games-leaderboards-before-publishing

Comment: You can do it only for unpublished leaderboard. In my case I need to reset previous year published leaderboard